# How to embed .ai files in HTML5?

Tags: html, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to directly embed .ai files in HTML5, so that the image is rendered automatically as per the size of the screen and resolution or do we need to convert the whole .ai files into .png of different sizes and then include them within.

Comment: Browsers don't render .ai files, you could only set it up for those files to be downloaded. You need to convert them to something a browser can render: png, jpeg, gif, svg (partially supported), etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could export it as a [SVG](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) file, and embed that in your website. SVG is a vector format that all modern browsers understand. Adobe Illustrator should be able to export drawings to SVG, since it is a very widely used format.

Since SVG is a vector graphics format, it can be rendered at any size and still look nice and sharp.

Comment: how do I convert ai files it to svg file ?

Comment: If you have Adobe Illustrator, it's just a matter of opening the `.ai` file and saving it as or exporting it as `svg`. If you don't have Illustrator, there might be some free tools out there that can do this, but I'm not familiar with any.

Comment: There are also many online converting tools available. Search "convert .ai to .svg"