# How to convert .ai file to png

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I have html input type field in my upload form but I am not using `<form></form>` I just have bunch of text box select box and input file field . I need to upload the `.ai` file and show a display `.png/.jpg` image format for it in my own html

```
   jQuery("#main_gallery_view").prepend(thumbnail_html);
```

closest answer I could get was [How to embed .ai files in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880326/how-to-embed-ai-files-in-html5) but this answer also does not tell any way to convert the `.ai` files to image format`(jpg, png)`

So for my last try I am checking with stackoverflow experts.

Is this really feasible?

Is there any workaround to convert .ai files to  image format`(jpg, png)`   ?

I am using windows os and I will be saving it in my CDN S3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this in the browser.

Depending on your hosting environment and operating system you can upload the `.ai` Adobe Illustrator file to your back-end and then run a script to convert it to SVG for example using a tool like this for Linux, UniConvertor, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/uniconvertor.1.html

Then you would have to retrieve the processed SVG and then embed that on your page and then follow methodologies from this question/answer to process it into PNG in the browser: [Convert embedded SVG to PNG in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433806/convert-embedded-svg-to-png-in-place)

Due to the many variables and ambiguity in terms of your back-end, it is impossible to be more specific, however the general flow should ring true no-matter what your back-end system be.

Comment: Is it posssible to all this in one upload click ?

Comment: Perhaps, not sure. All depends on your backend but should be possible yes.

Comment: lets say I upload the .ai file in my CDN and then which convertor to be used for converting it to svg using cdn url

Comment: @hitesh this doesn't make sense.  You can only upload it to a server you control and then you would process it depending on your operating system.  Please stop trying to get people to do your work for you.  You are being a help-vampire.

Comment: I am sorry if you felt like that . I was not trying make anybody work . I was just looking for solution to convert the ai file to png which so far I did not get in Google

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!! is there any other converter for windows ..since http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/uniconvertor.1.html this one in for command line tool for ubuntu